# Generate URL with Query String in Play framework templates

Tags: templates, playframework, routes

I'm using play 1.1, I have a URL mapping routes file as,

`*    /show/{id}/    TestController.show`

and TestController is specified as

`public static void show(String id){}`

When I use above route in my HTML template by `@{TestController.show(id)}`, I would expect to render as `/show/23/` in the browser address bar, but like this instead its rendered as default mapping(`/TestController/show?id=23`) which has least priority in routes file. Can you please help me how do we render the URL as `http://localhost:9000/show/23/`?

Comment: could you please write a sample what do you expect?

Comment: Most probably the id you're using in template to built is not a string but Long or int, than you should use: public static void show(Long id){ ... action's body ...}

Comment: Fine, posted an answer, accept it please to let people know, that's propoer way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actions arguments has to be the same type as these passed in template so if you built href in template with `@{TestController.show(id)}` where id is porbably type of `Long` or `int` declare your action with the same argument.

```
public static void show(Long id){
  ... action's body ...
}
```